# neo4j how to count distinct relationships group by node?

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph db of Node `User (properties: uid, name)` and Relationship `Invitation (properties: invitation_id, invitation_time)`.

The relationship is built when one user invite other users. That means every time one user invites, it will build the same relationship between him and the users he invited.

I want to count the unique invitations of each user.
My cyper query is:

```
match (u:User)-[r:Invitation]->()
return u, count(distinct r)
order by count(distinct r) desc
```

Instead of meet my expectation, this query did not drop the duplicates.
So what should be the right query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by myself just after posting the question:

```
match (u:User)-[r:Invitation]->()
return u, count(distinct r.invitation_id)
order by count(distinct r.invitation_id) desc
```